# Java call "addActionListener" from "FocusListener"

Tags: java, actionlistener, focuslistener

I have JTextField. I need to save the changes, if user writes something in it and then lost the focus(like click some where else)

```
mMaxLabelLength = new JTextField();
mMaxLabelLength.addActionListener(this);

public void focusGained(FocusEvent fe)
{
    System.out.println("4");
    mMaxLabelLength.addActionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe)
{
    System.out.println("5");
    mMaxLabelLength.addActionListener(this);
}

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    //Do something
    }
```

The problem is I  am not able to call "actionPerformed" from "focusLost/focusGain". I need to keep the "actionPerformed" as separate method as I am calling it from another places also.

Comment: Don't call `mMaxLabelLength.addActionListener(this);` from `focusLost()` & `focusGained()`. Otherwise you would end up with a 1000 listeners on the same `JTextField`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to do exactly the same thing when the focus is lost as what you're already doing in `actionPerformed()`, right, right. So, do just that:

```
@Override
public void focusLost(FocusEvent fe) {
    doSomething();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    doSomething();
}

private void doSomething() {
    // ...
}
```